# How can I calculate $ \sum_{k=35}^{80} {80 \choose k}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

How can I calculate $$ \sum_{k=35}^{80} {80 \choose k}$$ ?

I don't have idea how to calculate it, and I will be happy to listen some ideas , hints.

Comment: You can use a calculator or you ask me!

Comment: I don't think there is any easy way of working this out other than computation

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(BinomialCoefficient%5B80,n%5D,%7Bn,35,80%7D)) gives $1076839769625942289509138$.  Any reason to expect the sum to have a sensible, simple expression?

Answer (score 10):

Not really sure what kind of an expression you are after, but you could notice that $$ \sum_{k=0}^{80} \binom{80}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{80} \binom{80}{k}1^{k}1^{80-k} = (1+1)^{80} = 2^{80}, $$
and by symmetry,
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{39} \binom{80}{k} = \sum_{k=41}^{80} \binom{80}{k}, $$
so that 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{80} \binom{80}{k} = 2\sum_{k=41}^{80} \binom{80}{k}+\binom{80}{40}, $$
giving
$$ \sum_{k=41}^{80} \binom{80}{k} = \frac{2^{80}-\binom{80}{40}}{2}. $$
Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=35}^{80} \binom{80}{k} &=  \binom{80}{35} + \binom{80}{36} + \binom{80}{37} + \binom{80}{38} + \binom{80}{39} + \binom{80}{40} + \sum_{k=41}^{80} \binom{80}{k}\\[0.2cm]
&= \binom{80}{35} + \binom{80}{36} + \binom{80}{37} + \binom{80}{38} + \binom{80}{39} + \binom{80}{40} + \frac{2^{80}-\binom{80}{40}}{2}\\[0.2cm]
&= \binom{80}{35} + \binom{80}{36} + \binom{80}{37} + \binom{80}{38} + \binom{80}{39} + \frac{1}{2}\binom{80}{40} + 2^{79}. \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You can use Binomial Theorem and observe and the sum up to 40 is about half of a total. So it is enough to have the sum from 35 to 40 and our task seems to be easy. The total from 0 to 80 is of course $2^{80}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gaussian Hypergeometric function:

$$\sum_{k=35}^{80}\dbinom{80}{k} = \dbinom{80}{35}{_2F_1}(1,-45;36;-1)$$

More generally:

$$\sum_{k=r}^n \dbinom{n}{k} = \dbinom{n}{r}{_2F_1}(1,r-n;r+1;-1)$$